# Redactor I icons missing

Tags: redactor

As you can see from the image below, the icons are missing from redactor I. Has anybody else had this issue? Running dev tools in chrome shows no errors.

Bold, for example has the following css selector:

.re-bold:before {
  content: "\e618";
}

I see that the @font-face src is base64 encoded right into the CSS file, so the issue can't be because of a missing font file for the icons can it?

[image: Missing icons in Redactor I]

Here is the bold link inspected in dev tools:

[image]

As you see there is no mention of .re-icon in the markup, but the only declaration of the font-family: 'RedactorFont' is for the .re-icon selector class. So adding .re-button::before to the selector that declares the font results in this:

[image]

...Close but not quite right. I shouldn't be editing these files, but am just doing so to help diagnose this. Presumably this redactor.css file shouldn't be referenced... it should be redactori.css?

Comment: Here is the markup for the start of the text editor in the admin area, notice id="redactor-toolbar-0"....... <div class="redactor-box" role="application" dir="ltr"><ul class="redactor-toolbar" id="redactor-toolbar-0"

Comment: Although the config for this particular Redactor instance requests 'formatting' in its redactori syntax, the field does not show 'formatting'. All this is pointing towards the fact that this field is Redactor II even though it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seemed that for some reason my fields said they were Redactor I but were in fact Redactor II.

Reinstalling Redactor I did the trick.

Comment: You probably created a new Rich Text field (non-Redactor I) after you had installed the plugin, which will cause conflicts like this.

Comment: I think I may have either done that Brandon, or perhaps incorrectly synced the DB after installing the plugin, thus making all Rich Text fields Redactor II again!

Comment: Ugh — Redactor II… It would be nice if Redactor I being installed could remove "Rich Text" as being an option, as this was a pretty vexing issue